# Ruby C extension exception message encoding

Tags: ruby, exception, encoding, odbc

Hi I'm recently handling with ruby-odbc.

There's an exception raised by ruby-odbc according to my logic and the Active Record lib should catch it. But the encoding of this exception's message is ASCII-8BIT which will raise another encoding incompatible exception. I don't want to modify Active Record for now or use tiny_tds instead(for now).

So I wondered if there's  a way I could change the encoding of exception's message to a given encoding?

I tried to convert the error message before passing to rb_raise,and it didn't work. The result is still ASCII-8BIT.
So am I doing something stupid cause anystring comes out of ruby c extension is all ASCII-8BIT  or I've made mistakes during the conversion?
Any thoughts?

=================Append the whole background===============
I modified and recompiled the odbc.c file based on the cloudvolumes/ruby-odbc, mainly in this function:

```
static VALUE  stmt_prep_int(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self, int mode)
```

For all the sentences like below:

```
rb_raise(Cerror, "%s",msg);
```

I replaced with:

```
rb_odbc_raise_error(Cerror,  msg);
```

Which this new function is defined as:

```
static VALUE rb_odbc_raise_error(VALUE err,char * msg){
VALUE e;
VALUE vmsg = rb_str_new2(msg);
#ifdef USE_RB_ENC
rb_enc_associate_index(vmsg,rb_enc );
msg = rb_string_value_cstr(&vmsg);
#endif
e = rb_exc_new2(err,msg);
rb_exc_raise(e);
return Qnil;
}
```

Note,the definition of USE_RB_ENC and rb_enc (utf8)come from repo:https://github.com/cloudvolumes/ruby-odbc.

The ruby script that will raise an exception is like below:

```
begin
  cfg = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
  if cfg && cfg[:adapter] == "sqlserver"
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |connection|
      domain_name   = ENV['USERDOMAIN']
      computer_name = "#{ENV['COMPUTERNAME']}中文$"
      name = "#{domain_name}\\#{computer_name}"
      puts "Granting database access to #{name.encode(Encoding.locale_charmap)}"
      connection.execute("CREATE LOGIN [#{name}] FROM WINDOWS")
  end
else
  puts "Database is not configured or is not SQL Server"
end
rescue Interrupt
  raise
rescue Exception => e
  #do something.
end
```

This script should raise an exception of

```
"42000 (15401) [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Windows NT user or group 'ZHUO\APPMANAGERDEV中文$' not found. Check the name again.".
```

However,when the exception is catched by **activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adater.rb** below, since the rails is set utf-8 and e.message has encoding of ASCII-8BIT,there will be an exeption raised:

```
" Exception Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8".
```

Thus the original error message can't be seen at all.

```
    def log(sql, name = "SQL", binds = [])
      @instrumenter.instrument(
        "sql.active_record",
        :sql           => sql,
        :name          => name,
        :connection_id => object_id,
        :binds         => binds) { yield }
    rescue Exception => e
      message = "#{e.class.name}: #{e.message}: #{sql}"
      @logger.debug message if @logger
      exception = translate_exception(e, message)
      exception.set_backtrace e.backtrace
      raise exception
    end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is worth adding the exact text of the encoding exception (with first part of stack trace) to the question. It may help others see your diagnosis of the problem is correct, and also it would help someone else having a similar problem and searching the error message on the internet. Also, the context of your code - where are you adding this  - are you modifying and re-compiling the `ruby-odbc` gem extension, in which method?

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'm really not familiar with this :)  I've already edited my question @NeilSlater

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rb_enc_raise(rb_encoding *enc, VALUE exc, const char *fmt, ...)`.

Comment: This looks like it may help, but please consider adding some background detail and explanation to help explain what the OP's problem is and why this helps (I'm thinking only one or two sentences to make this a short paragraph answer) - information from or links to https://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/5650 and http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/error.c#1792 may also help

Comment: Wow! It works!!!!  Thanks so much! Btw, just in case someone else might meet the same issue , this function was not implemented yet in ruby 1.9.3, seems to be a 2.0 thing, so I just copied its function definition to my own program and it works like a charm.